# Image not showing

Tags: kubuntu

I am running the newest kubuntu lte version. I have samsung smart phone. When I plug my phone into the usb and open my DCIM folder, none of the images show up. All I get is green boxes with some design on them. I don't know why this is happening. I always allow access with my phone but still no images are shown. As soon as the image is on my desktop I can see it. This is very weird.

Comment: What happens when you double-click on the icons (green boxes with some design on them)?

Comment: Your details are unclear.  Are you running **Kubuntu 20.04 LTS**?  What is the model smartphone that you use?  After you connect the phone, do you change the settings on the phone for file transfer?  What green boxes are you talking about? (this is info that begs a screenshot).  What do you mean that the image is "on my desktop"?  Remember that our understanding of your issue is completely reliant on your description and right now, every detail is ambiguous. Please edit your question and make sure your details are clear, reproducible, and as unambiguous as possible.